# Hiding and showing a TableViewCell Button with button action in another TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am working with a comment and reply system for my iOS application. I had an issue with showing and hiding a button.

I created two XIB cells for my tableView one as a 'commentCell' and other is 'replyCell'. In comment cell I have a button (Reply) so when user clicks on "Reply" it should insert a cell at indexPath.row+1, in 'replyCell' I have a textview and two buttons (Submit) and (Cancel), so when user enter some text in textview and clicks on "Submit" it should store the reply text and textView shouldn't be able to edit after user clicks on "Submit" and if the user clicks on "Cancel" it should remove the 'replyCell' and delete row at indexPath.row

I am able to achieve all the above functionality..

Now my issue is:

When the user clicks "Reply" button in 'commentCell', it should hide the "Reply" Button and I am able to do it by setting (replyBtn.isHidden = true) in the "Reply" button action. But, when user clicks on "Cancel" button in the 'replyCell' the "Reply" button in the 'commentCell' should show again and I don't get any idea on how to show the "Reply" button in "commentCell" by setting (replyBtn.isHidden = false) in "Cancel" button action.

The issue is, I can't access the replyBtn property in 'replyCell' as it is the property of "commentCell".

How to do it???

I hope you understand what I am trying to convey...

These are my protocols and tableView delegate methods in UICommentTableViewController:

```
protocol UICommentReply {

    func replyToCommentAtIndexPath(cell: UICommentTableViewCell)
}

protocol UICancelReply {

    func cancelReplytoComment(cell: UICommentReplyTableViewCell)
}

class UICommentTableViewController: UITableViewController,UICommentReply, UICancelReply {

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return tableContent.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

        let row = indexPath.row
        let post = self.tableContent[row]
        switch post.type {
        case .Comment:
            let comment = post as! Comment
            let commentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UICommentTableViewCell
            commentCell.delegate = self
            commentCell.level = comment.level
            return commentCell
        case .Reply:

            let replyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "replyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UICommentReplyTableViewCell
            replyCell.delegate = self

            return replyCell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

   func replyToCommentAtIndexPath(cell: UICommentTableViewCell) {

        print(#function)
        if let path = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: path.row + 1, section: path.section)
            self.tableContent.insert(Reply(), at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)

    }

    }

    func cancelReplytoComment(cell: UICommentReplyTableViewCell) {

        print(#function)
        if let path = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: path.row, section: path.section)
            if self.tableContent[indexPath.row].type == .Reply {
                self.tableContent.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)

            }
        }
    }

}
```

in UICommentTableViewCell:

```
@IBDesignable class UICommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
 @IBOutlet weak var controlReplyButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: UICommentReply?

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

        controlReplyButton.setTitle("Reply", for: .normal)

        self.setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        self.controlReplyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleReplyButton(sender:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    func handleReplyButton(sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {

        controlReplyButton.isHidden = true

        self.delegate?.replyToCommentAtIndexPath(cell: self)
    }
}
```

in UICommentReplyTableViewCell:

```
class UICommentReplyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cancelReply: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var postReplyBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var replyTextView: UITextView!

    var delegate: UICancelReply?

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

        self.setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        self.cancelReply.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelReplyButton(sender:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
 }

    func cancelReplyButton(sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {

        self.delegate?.cancelReplytoComment(cell: self)

    }
}
```

This is the code I had so far, and help me with it.

[Comment Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjPNV.png)

[Comment Reply Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZMXR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first have to access the `commentCell` in your `cancel` button action and then access it's `replyBtn` property.

Since you haven't shared any code, I don't know the details of your code structure. However, you would have to change your code to something like this

```
//Where ever the implementation of cancel button action is written in your code
cancelButtonAction {

    //Replace INDEXPATH with the calculated indexPath for your reply cell
    //Replace YOURCUSTOMCELL with appropriate UITableViewCell class
    if let replyCell = tablview.cellForRow(at: INDEXPATH) as? YOURCUSTOMCELL {
        replyCell.replyBtn.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In your `cancelReplyToComment` method, you are using the indexPath for the passed cell which is a `Reply` cell and not the `Comment` cell. You have to look at your business logic and calculate the indexPath for your `Comment` cell from the passed in `Reply` cell. e.g: if your comment cell is just after your reply cell, your `cancelReplyToComment` method would become

```
func cancelReplytoComment(cell: UICommentReplyTableViewCell) {
    print(#function)
    if let path = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: path.row, section: path.section)
        if self.tableContent[indexPath.row].type == .Reply {
            self.tableContent.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)

        }
        let indexPathCommentCell = NSIndexPath(row: path.row + 1, section: path.section)
        //Here, 1 is added to row because the assumption is that the comment cell
        //is just after the reply cell. If it was the other way around,
        //you would have to subtract 1. Basically, you need to calculate
        //the difference between your comment and reply cell
        if let commentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathCommentCell) as? YOURCOMMENTCELLCLASS {
            //Access your comment cell's button here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I've updated my question, added my code. Go through it and tell me, is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Yeah! I've to use indexPath for passed cell to delete the same cell when called upon that function. And if I give the indexPath for the commentCell as you suggested, it will delete the entire comment cell instead of deleting the replyCell.

Comment: No, I want to delete the replyCell and at the same time I want to show the Reply Button in the commentCell. I am adding images of my design so you can understand more..Thank you

Comment: Read the updated answer again. I think you missed the point. The suggestion in the update is in addition to what you are already doing. That is to say that you will need two `indexPath`s (replyCell and commentCell). Since you already have the indexPath for replyCell, you will have to calculate the commentCell's indexPath based on how you have laid it out. Then access the commentCell using this new indexPath. Once you have that, you can access your reply Button's property

Comment: Yeah! I got it now and I'll try it mate. I hope it works..Thanks.

Comment: Yeah! it's working.. Man you are Genius. Thanks for the help. I couldn't accept the answer because of low reputation. I am just beginner.. Anyway lots of Thanks to you mate...

Comment: No worries. Glad to be of help

Answer (score -1):

I just implemented a quick and simple reply and commenting system for you.

I think it can fix your problem as well.

You access your hide/show/reply button from the comment cell, expand and collapse the tableview with a indent for comments .

[SwiftCR GitHub](https://github.com/TheM4hd1/SwiftCR)

Comment: Thanks for the help but, I have some complicated UI and one more thing I don't want to hide and show the replies. If there is a reply it should show by default and if there is no reply we should be able to add one.

Comment: you just need to change isOpen property of cell to true. and remove the view comments button. thats it.

Comment: thanks for the reply bro. can you help me with the integration??  I will send you the api and the sample design of my app.I have tried a lot of ways but I am not able to do it. It will a lot of help to me and I will be in your debt forever for this.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: open an issue on SwiftCR, i try to help

Comment: mate I don't know how to do it.. But I raised new question on stackOverFlow here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50312995/how-to-implement-comments-and-reply-system-in-ios-swift) please try to help me there. Thank you very much.